# Annotation that throws an exception if the conditions are not met

Tags: java, exception, annotations, annotation-processing

My class has is a boolean *variable*, by default, it has the value false, during execution it can change to true. There are also methods that can only be called when the *variable* is true.

I want to do something like:

```java
@ConfirmedOnly
public void method() {
    // some code
}
```

It will throw an exception when *variable* is not true.

---

Do I have to write an annotation handler like *Lombok*?

Comment: why do you need an annotation for that?

Comment: @Stultuske This is a bit easier and nicer to read than the "copy-paste" check at the beginning of the method

Comment: not really, since it wouldn't be usable for other classes. my first guess was aop, but then you can't change the value of that field. Besides, how much easier to read is a copy-paste annotation compared to a copy-paste call to validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to give behavior to an annotation, you must write an annotation processor.  (Lombok is an example of an annotation processor.)

An annotation is not a method that gets called at run time.  It is a marker in the source code with no behavior.  (The [Java Language Specification section 9.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7) says "An *annotation* is a marker which associates information with a program construct, but has no effect at run time.")  An annotation processor gives it behavior.  The annotation processor operates at compile time, for example by issuing errors or by changing the source code.